# Binary search algorithm code won't execute

Tags: sorting, data-structures, binary-search

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int binary_search(int, int[], int);

int binary_search(int key,int arra[],int len){
    int low=0;
    int high=len-1;
    int mid=(low+high)/2;

    while(low<=high){
        if(arra[mid]==key){return mid;}
        else if (arra[mid]>key){high=mid-1;}

        else {low=mid+1;}
    }
     return -1;
}


int main()

{

       int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf("%d",len);
    binary_search(2,arr,len);
    return 0;
}
```

So, trying to run this and i don't get any output whatsoever, intially i had the code taking input of the array from the user but it wasn't working then either so even after simplifying it and adding the array in the code itself hasn't solved the problem. Can someone point it out?

Comment: You don't see this? `printf("%d",len);` note that if the console window closes on program completion it might have flashed by too quickly to notice.  You could add a user input "press any key to exit" after the output from binary_search is computed.  You also need a prinff to show that result.

Comment: no the length does not get printed, that's why i tried adding that to see if it would. @DaveS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never changing the variable `mid`. It is always `3` and since `arr[3] > 2` (second condition), the while loop is never breaking. The `low` is stuck at `0` and high is stuck at `2` and it is running infinitely.

```
int binary_search(int key,int arra[],int len){
    int low=0;
    int high=len-1;
    int mid=(low+high)/2;

    while(low<=high){            
        int mid;            
        mid=(low+high)/2;         
        if(arra[mid]==key){
            printf("Found at %d",mid);
            return 1;
        }       
        else if (arra[mid]>key){
            high=mid-1;
        }         
        else{
            low=mid+1;
        }        
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Good catch.  Adding a `printf` in the while loop would have shown this.  Or using a debugger and single-stepping through the code.

Comment: You're right added a printf statement instead of return mid and it was printing it infinitely, so i realized i had to add the mid variable in the while loop so it keeps changing once the low or high variable get incrememented or decremented. Yet, the code still does not produce an output.
`while(low<=high){
            int mid;
            mid=(low+high)/2;
            if(array[mid]==key){printf("Found at %d",mid);}
        else if (array[mid]>key){high=mid-1;}
        else {low=mid+1;}

           }`

Yet, it still prints the correct index infintely.

Comment: When the condition `if(array[mid]==key)` is satisfied, it should return from the function. You missed that. I have updated the answer with the correct code.